# How to align a td text to the left of the table

Tags: html, jsp, html-table

I have created a table in JSP file to look like this:

#### JSP Code:

```
<table style="width: 832px;" >
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 45px;text-align: left;" align="left"><%=episodeDate %></td>
        <td style="width: 7px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 257px;text-align: left;" ><%=careprovidername %></td>
        <td style="width: 7px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 260px;text-align: left;" ><%=docatorname %></td>
        <td style="width: 6px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 250px;text-align: left;"><%=purposeType %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But what I get is display in the below image.

[image: Table]

My problem is that the 5th and 7th td data are not shown well aligned. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Can't replicate this using raw HTML...

Comment: try to add `table-layout: fixed;` to your table

Comment: Perhaps if you post the view source, it would help us see what has been generated by the JSP. My suspicion is that you have <table><tr><td></td>*7</tr></table> <table><tr><td></td>*7</tr></table> <table><tr><td></td>*7</tr></table> <table><tr><td></td>*7</tr></table> <table><tr><td></td>*7</tr></table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Gintas K's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874504/how-to-align-a-td-text-to-the-left-of-the-table#comment26099996_17874504), I solved this problem by adding `table-layout: fixed;` to the styles for my `<table>`.

Answer (score 2):

In your JSP, you should be looping inside one table. By your code, it would seem that you are re-setting the values of your variables outside the visible code. If so, you are generating multiple 1 row tables. The fix then would be to set your java variables inside the < table > ... < / table > tags, creating just new TRs and TDs for each java object.

With a single table, your TDs should all align as you wished.

```
<table style="width: 832px;" >
<%
MyObject o; // which has those variables
for (int i=0; i<array_size; ++i){
    o = array[i]; %>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 45px;text-align: left;" align="left"><%= o.getEpisodeDate() %></td>
        <td style="width: 7px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 257px;text-align: left;" ><%= o.getCareproviderName() %></td>
        <td style="width: 7px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 260px;text-align: left;" ><%= o.getDocatorName() %></td>
        <td style="width: 6px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 250px;text-align: left;"><%= o.getPurposeType() %></td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

The idea here is to have:

```
<table>
    <tr> <td></td>*7 </tr>
    <tr> <td></td>*7 </tr>
    <tr> <td></td>*7 </tr>
    <tr> <td></td>*7 </tr>
    <tr> <td></td>*7 </tr>
    <tr> <td></td>*7 </tr>
</table>
```

So the loop where you set the java variable values has to be inside the < table> ... < /table> tags, not before.

Comment: `@AngelWarrior` thanks for answer but i also used `java variables before < table > ... < / table > tags`

Comment: Yes, and you're getting another table for every java object, right? You only want one table if you want the cells to align.